# .htaccess RewriteCond for REMOTE_ADDR while behind Load Balancer?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, php, .htaccess, lamp

I have a web server behind a load-balancer.

I need to add a conditional redirect to my .htaccess in order to display a maintenance page whenever we take the site offline for maintenance. This part is straightforward:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/maintenance.php$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g?|png|gif) [NC]
RewriteRule .* /maintenance.php [R=302,L]
```

However I want to add in a condition that if the visitor's IP address is my own, it will not redirect me to the maintenance page and that I would be able to see and test the site as if it was online. This part is normally also straightforward:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^11\.111\.111\.111
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/maintenance.php$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g?|png|gif) [NC]
RewriteRule .* /maintenance.php [R=302,L]
```

However, because my web server is behind a load balancer, `REMOTE_ADDR` is resolved to the internal IP address of the Load Balance server.

How can I alter this to look for the forwarded IP address?  I know in PHP you can use `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']` to get the forwarded IP address. I've tried a few things in the `.htaccess` but no luck:

```
%{X_FORWARDED_FOR}
%{HTTP:X_FORWARDED_FOR}
%{HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR}
```

**SOLUTION**

I got the following to work:

```
%{HTTP:X-FORWARDED-FOR}
```

Comment: %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-For} is the correct one. Is it case sensitive?

Comment: All Caps worked for me. I guess it's not case sensitive or else it's an alias or something.

Comment: Do you really serve `.jpe` or `.jp` files?

Answer (score 15):

Use `%{HTTP:X-FORWARDED-FOR}` instead of `%{REMOTE_ADDR}`

Comment: I know you already answered it in your question, but you didn't have an answer below that matched.  Thank you for your answer!  Saved me today.

Answer (score 2):

You need [mod_rpaf](http://stderr.net/apache/rpaf/). This module will rewrite REMOTE_ADDR in apache with another header, such as x-forwarded-for. Very useful for making PHP apps behave with load balancers.

Answer (score 0):

http://blog.janjonas.net/2010-01-04/apaches-mod_rewrite-mod_proxy-use-reverse-proxy-request-headers-for-rewrite-rules

Might this be the answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you have two environments, say one production behind the load balance and a development or staging not behind the load balance, and you want to use the same .htaccess file, you will need both %{HTTP:X-FORWARDED-FOR} and %{REMOTE_ADDR} -- assign IP addresses to both conditions.

Comment: Also, on some apache servers, the backslash will confuse the server.  Simply put !^123.123.123.123 (without the backslashes, to mean if not IP 123.123.123.123) if you cannot get an iteration with backslashes to work.